# Convert text hours and minutes to int

Tags: php

I want to convert my text to minute in int.

my text sometimes look likes this:

```
$time = "1 hr 46 min";
```

it should be

```
106
```

sometimes look likes this:

```
$time = "50 min";
```

it should be

```
50
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can multiply the hour part by 60

Comment: How can I parse $time? @FelippeDuarte

Comment: umm, what you have tried..? you can somehow rely on regex to match the hour and minute part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is consistent, you can do it like this: split the string by space. If the result has more than two pieces, then you have minutes and hours. If not, then it's just minutes.

```
$parts = explode(' ', $time);
if (isset($parts[2])) {
    $minutes = $parts[0] * 60 + $parts[2];
} else{
    $minutes = $parts[0];
}
```

This is very much dependent on a consistent format for the input. If there are extra spaces or text parts, it will break.